# NumericUpDown control xaml Windows 8 Metro

Tags: c#, xaml, numericupdown

So far I could not find a NumericUpDown control for c#/xaml Windows 8 Metro. Does anybody know if this is available? I do not want to pay for a Telerik control.

P.S I do not want to work with the slider control.

Comment: This is a mistake, NUD is drastically unusable on a touch screen.  You need to create a UI that can be operated with a fat finger.  Just composite your own with two big buttons to inc/decrement a number.  Or a slider of course.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly agree with Hans Passant, that mostly there are better ways to handle numerical values. Besides that, there is the [Callisto XAML toolkit](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto). See [here](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/NumericUpDown) for a description of it's NumericUpDown control.